# Force a double to write the whole Number

Tags: java, double

How can I force a `double` in Java to print the whole number. Not like 1.65462165887E12.But like 1654621658874684?

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Format it appropriately. For example:

```
System.out.printf("%.1f", 1654621658874684.0);
```

Or you can use it like a String:

```
//"%.1f" this mean, how many number after the comma
String value = String.format("%.1f", 1654621658874684.0);
```

Be aware that `double` is not infinitely precise. It has a precision of about [15 to 17 decimal digits](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format). If you need floating-point numbers with arbitrary precision, use `BigDecimal` instead of `double`.

Comment: +1 for mentioning that the lack of precision in doubles might be part of the issue.

Comment: Thanks for the tip with BigDecimal

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`String.format()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29):

```
System.out.println(String.format("%.0f", 1654621658874684.0d)); // prints 1654621658874684
```

Answer (score 1):

`String formatted = String.format("%f", dblNumber);`

Answer (score 0):

I use something like

```
if((long) d == d)
  System.out.println((long) d);
else
  System.out.println(d);
```

long can have 18 digits whereas `double` has 15-16 digits of accuracy at best.